# Subtle difference between ATtiny parts?

Tags: microcontroller, attiny

I want to purchase 20 MHz ATtiny85 chips in SOIC-8 on a full reel from Mouser. I found these two variants:

- [ATtiny85-20S**U**R](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/ATTINY85-20SUR/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuRdXZgphLdVrSuoRtxaCoY)
- [ATtiny85-20S**H**R](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/ATTINY85-20SHR/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtQuSbTnHsVtoUalgkySMpy)

I have studied the specifications but cannot for the life of me find the difference between the two, and I don't want to order a full reel of the wrong part if there is any difference between them. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On page 13 of the datasheet, you can see the Order codes and what they mean.

[image: enter link description here]

In this case, H and U mean the finish or plating on the pins.

Comment: Uhh, ok... should I care which finish I get on the pins?

Comment: @DavidHögberg The NiPdAu is not lead free. Its easier to solder, no tin whisker issue,  but you know, lead. Matt Tine is lead free. Use the one that conforms to your needs to be lead free (Rohs) or not.

Comment: @Passerby NiPdAu should be lead-free, futhermore the [SHR listed as RoHS on distributors](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/ATTINY85-20SHR/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvqv2n3s2xjsT5mflYUGM1LfVjbNVgt8ms%3d).  Pd stands for Palladium, while Pb stands for Lead.  I think, this calls for another Hello Kitty.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, while NiPdAu may be lead free, is "NiPdAu lead finish" lead free?

Comment: @slebetman Depends if "lead" refers to the element (`Pb`, pronounced 'led') or ["An insulated metallic wire for electrical devices and equipment."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lead#Noun_2) (pronounced 'leed'). Presumably the latter, especially considering ["NiPdAu-finish component leads" and "NiPdAu-finished leads", not to mention "With the push for Pb-free electronics, TI decided to improve on the NiPd finish performance with Pb-free solders. The result is the NiPdAu finish."](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza026/szza026.pdf)

Comment: @Bob  [as an aside]  English language is frugal when it comes to using letters for making words.  English language doesn't squander them.

Comment: Also, in the notes above, in point 2, it says that "All packages are Pb-free".

Comment: @DavidHögberg I can't find anything specifically from Atmel to confim, but the general consensus is that the NiPdAu is lead-free. The Lead refers to the pins. This faq http://www.cypress.com/file/97726/download from Cypress says NiPdAu is preferred/recommend over  Matte Tin. And the part about Tin whiskers still stands. NiPdAu seems to be fairly consistent in resisting whisker growth.

Answer (score 4):

From the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/36/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATti-276549.pdf), page 11:

> 3. Code indicators: H = NiPdAu lead finish, U/N = matte tin, R = tape & reel.